# Implementing stale-while-revalidate with service worker, behaves like cache-only on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, caching, service-worker

I'm currently implementing a simple service worker to improve the performance of a website, the website serves the cached assets and then once the page has loaded quietly checks the ETAG to see if it has changed since the last visit, if it has it downloads the resource in the background and caches it for the next time.

I tried changing an image on the server, on desktop chrome updated the resource after 20 minutes while on android the cache has never been updated since the moment the sw was installed, which is 16 hours ago. I can't seem to understand what's the issue, maybe you guys can help. It's worth mentioning this is my first time writing a service worker and with asyncronous javascript in general.

This is my code:

```
 const staticAssets = [
    //Resources I want to be served using stale-while-revalidate
];

self.addEventListener('install', async event =>{
    const cache = await caches.open('rmi');
    cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch',event =>{
    const req = event.request;
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(req));
});

async function cacheFirst(req){
    try{
        const cachedResponse = await caches.match(req)
        if  (cachedResponse == null)
            throw "Not In Cache";

        const cache = await caches.open('rmi');
        try{
            return  cachedResponse;
        } finally {
            addToCache(req.url,cache);
        }

    } catch(error) {
        const res = await fetch(req);
        return res;
    }
};

function addToCache(req,cache){

    fetch(req,{cache:'no-cache'}).then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new TypeError('Bad Response Status');
    }
    return cache.put(req, response);
    })

}
```

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use an existing library? I can recommend [Google Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/). It implements a [stale while revalidate](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-runtime-caching.StaleWhileRevalidate). cache strategy. Also check out the [Offline Cookbook's implementation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#stale-while-revalidate).

Comment: I can surely use a library, but I'm currently trying to learn async javascript and service workers and writing one myself would probably be the best way. The Offline Cookbook is really useful and shows some cool techniques to maximise performance like returning promises, but gives me no hint on what might be wrong with my code.

I don't need to get something working on a deadline, I'm just trying to learn some new stuff.